# HTTP 303 See Other - Content

Tags: rest, http-post, http-status-codes, http-status-code-303

If I want to return a status code of `303 See Other` when a client `POST`s data that already exists, am I allowed to return that data in the content (body) of the response (in addition to setting `Location`), or must the client then `GET` the `Location`?

I would like to avoid requiring the client HTTP to make two HTTP calls if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatically, the client should retrieve the data with a GET request.